Is there a way to get Docusaurus to tell me about all missing images / test for missing images?
When our CI/CD scripts build Docusaurus, we occassionally run into cases where someone forgot to git add an image:
98.49 Error: Image docs/add-ons/adjustment-period-ex.png used in docs/add-ons/custom-menus.mdx not found.
#13 98.49     at async Promise.all (index 2)
#13 98.49 Error: Image docs/contacts/contacts-6.png used in docs/contacts/contacts.mdx not found.
#13 98.49     at async Promise.all (index 2)
#13 98.49 Error: Image docs/customization/email-payment.jpg used in docs/customization/emailing.mdx not found.
#13 98.49     at async Promise.all (index 5)

This is great! We want the build to fail in this case.
But sometimes they forgot many images in the same article. In this case, Docusaurus will tell us about just the first image in the article instead of all of the missing ones.
Is there a way to get Docusaurus to tell us about all of the missing images at once, so that we can push this back on whoever forgot to commit them all, and they can fix them all at once instead of fixing one at a time, and waiting for the build to fail again so they know which other images they forgot to commit?

This seems to be impossible with the current code base:

The Error: Image <...> used in <...> not found. is thrown here in the function ensureImageFileExist(),

which in turn is used by function getImageAbsolutePath(),

which in turn is used by function processImageNode(),

which is called by the main transformImage plugin function:
 visit(root, 'image', (node: Image, index, parent) => {
   promises.push(
     processImageNode([node, index, parent!], {
       ...options,
       filePath: vfile.path!,
     }),
   );
 });


If I read this function right, I goes through ALL the images referenced in a document and transforms / validates them - and exits / throws if the FIRST missing image is found.

To achieve what you want, that code would have to be adapted to handle these errors and collect them before exiting. As I see no extension points in the code, that would have to be done in the code itself. Maybe you can try a feature request. Good luck!


